# Most efficient algorithm to raise 2 to the n-th power using only sums?

Tags: python, algorithm

The following algorithm needs O(n) time. Is this improvable?

```
def powerOfTwo(n):
  a = 1
  if (n>0):
    a=2
    while (n>1):
      a=(a+a)
      n=(n-1)
  return a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments(and pointed out by @Mark Ransom), you can simplify your code to:

```
def powerOfTwo(n):     
    a = 1     
    for _ in range(n):       
        a += a    
    return a
```

Unless you have pre-calculated values `2^n` for different `n`, there's no way you can calculate `2^n` using only sum operations in less than O(n).

### Proof

Let's prove it. Let's assume there are `k` initial values `a[i]` (in your example, `k=1`) that are used for calculating `2^n`.

Then, at the first iteration, you do some `m` additions. So, the maximum number that you can get is `max(a[i])*m`. At the second iteration, you do `m` additions again and the maximum number is `max(a[i])*m*m` and so on.

How many loop iterations do we need to reach `2^n`? For this, we need to solve an inequality:

```
max(a[i])*(m^l) >= 2^n         | take log from both sides
->
log(max(a[i])*(m^l)) >= n
->
log(max(a[i]) + log(m^l) >= n  |  
->
log(m^l) >= n - log(max(a[i])  | exclude log(max(a[i]) because it's constant 
->
log(m^l) >= n
->
l*log(m) >= n
->
l >= n / log(m)
```

The number of iterations `l` linearly depends on `n` since `log(m)` is a finite number. Hence, the time complexity remains O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the school algorithm for multiplication (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) only with additions and bit tests. If this is allowed, you can compute the power with [exponention by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

The complexity of this algorithm should be faster than O(n).

Comment: (For powers of two/multiplication by two, the code in the question *is* the school book algorithm for multiplication. While *squaring* sidesteps *multiplication*, it is not `using only sums`.)

Comment: @greybeard The code in the question computes the power of two, and it doesn‘t multiply two given arbitrary numbers. And yes, squaring and exponentiation needs a multiplications, but for binary digits you can implement multiplication with addition and bit tests (please note the if my post) which is fast enough to let the complexity fall below that of the given algorithm.